# How do I use the data in an object from one JS file in another JS file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 and I am trying to export the data in a method called Users to another method in a different js file called:

**users.js**

```
 export default class Users {

   var User() {
    Newuser = {
        firstName: 'Tony',
        lastname: 'franklyn',
        email: `franky@gmail.com`,
        password: 'Franklin123'
    }

    return Newuser;
  }

}
```

login.js

```
import Users from '../data/user';

const newie = new Users();

export default class Signup {

    async Register() {

      await t
     .typeText(this.firstName,newie.firstName)

     }

  }
```

Whenever my program executes I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined.**

I am truly baffled by this, note I dont have as much js experience.

Comment: `NewUser` needs to have `let`, `var` or `const` in front of it, also you are not calling the method `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

The problem is that NewUsers is wrapped under a method called `User()`. Instead of `newie.firstName`, it should be: `newie.User().firstName`;

Couple of things:

1. Always define your variables, preferably with `const`, and `let`. Avoid using `var`. This will prevent the global scope from being contaminated, and your variable from being overwritten.

Therefore, instead of `NewUsers`, it should be:

```
export default class Users {

   // This is a method name. 
   // Methods do not use var, const or let
   User() {
   // This would be the variable. 
   // You would use const, because you are not
   // reassigning (using equals sign) its content.
    const Newuser = {
        firstName: 'Tony',
        lastname: 'franklyn',
        email: `franky@gmail.com`,
        password: 'Franklin123'
    }

    return Newuser;
  }

}
```

2. If what you want is to export data, you don't necessarily need a class. This should work fine:

**users.js**

```
module.exports = {
firstName: 'Tony',
        lastname: 'franklyn',
        email: `franky@gmail.com`,
        password: 'Franklin123'

}
```

If you'd like more than one user, create an array:

```
module.exports = [{
    firstName: 'Tony',
            lastname: 'franklyn',
            email: `franky@gmail.com`,
            password: 'Franklin123'

    }, 
  {
firstName: 'Pedro',
            lastname: 'Smith',
            email: `smith@gmail.com`,
            password: 'Smithy123'

    }
}
]
```

And in login.js

```
// When you import Users, it will bring the properties you defined above.
import Users from '../data/user';


export default class Signup {

    async Register() {

      await t
     .typeText(this.firstName,Users.firstName)

     }

  }
```

// If you went with the multiple users approach, then:

Instead of `Users.firstName`, you'd use:

```
// Fraklyn    
Users[0].firstName

// Pedro
Users[1].firstName
```

Comment: Hi there, I want to have multiple users i.e. a new user object, a power user object etc. In your answer you used module.exports, I am assuming I cannot have multiple objects exported?

Comment: Yes, you can! You wrap the whole object in an array. You can also export variables! Check my updated answer.

Comment: Additionally, if you're planning to store passwords, remember to "hash" them. In English this will create some gibberish text that it will be difficult for someone to guess which password is.  https://www.abeautifulsite.net/hashing-passwords-with-nodejs-and-bcrypt

Comment: you are so awesome bro. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome ;) I remember when I started as well. It's good to help! Keep it up